# how to filter,search,groupby with odoo query

Tags: python, odoo-10

in Stock move  I want to  filter by some specific date and groupby product_id,location_dest_id and sum product_uom_quantity.

```py
@api.multi
    def compute_report(self):

       record_move= self.env['stock.move'].search([('date','>=',self.start_date)]).
        .read_group([('date','>=',self.start_date)],[sum('product_uom_quantity')],['product_id','location_dest_id'])
        return {'record_move': record_move}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
domain = [('date', '=', specific_date),
          ('product_id', '=', id_of_the_product),
          ('location_dest_id', '=', id_of_location)]
record = self.env['stock.move'].search(domain)
sum=0
for rec in record:
   sum = sum + rec.product_uom_quantity
return sum
```

`I want to groupby all product_id and location_dest_id since i have plenty articles`

then read all product_id & location_dest_id into a list

```py
p = self.env['model_of_product'].search([])


_product=[]
# collect all product id
for product in p:
    _product.append(product.id)

box = []
for _p in _product:
    domain = [  ('date', '=', specific_date),
                ('product_id', '=', _p)]
    record = self.env['stock.move'].search(domain)
    sum_of_stock = 0
    sum_of_client = 0
    # box will contain sets of [product_id, sum_of_stock, sum_of_client ]
    for rec in record.search([('name', '=', 'Clients')]):
        sum_of_client = sum_of_client + rec.product_uom_quantity
    for rec in record.search([('name', '=', 'Stock')]):
        sum_of_stock = sum_of_stock + rec.product_uom_quantity

    box.append([_p, sum_of_stock, sum_of_client])
return box
```

Comment: I want to groupby all product_id and location_dest_id  since i have plenty articles

Comment: more than 100 and it will keep adding

Comment: this request is good but it give many line for each product I want one line per product and able to sum product_uom _quantity by location_dest_id="Clients" and   location_dest_id=Stock" any Idea please?

Comment: just set `for _l in _location:` as `for _l in [ Stock_id, Clients_id]:`

Comment: I dont kow the id of location since it's 2  record  in stock.location

Comment: `l = self.env['model_of_location'].search([('name', 'in', ['Stock', 'Clients'])])`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195894/discussion-between-amadou-tafsir-diallo-and-terrence-poe).